# create a dynamic function in excel based on a dropdown

Tags: excel

I am trying to use the `countifs` function on a range of cells with different numbers in them.  An example would be the `c4:c343` range and each row in the range has 20 numbers between 01-60.  I would like to have dropdowns to say pick 2 numbers (i.e. 3 and 45) and that would be plugged in dynamically into the function...."`=countifs(c4:c343, L5, c4:c343. M5)`". Now I'm thinking `L5` would be one dropdown with choices 1-60 and `M5` would be the second dropdown. 
The result would show me how many times in the range that those 2 numbers were in there......I hope I explained this properly.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fix your "criteria" syntax and break the counting up into two `COUNTIF` functions. You want your formula to look like this:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(C4:C343, "=" & L1), COUNTIF(C4:C343, "=" & M1))
```

The criteria is now a string that is based on the values in cells L5 and M5. You need to sum two `COUNTIF` functions because `COUNTIFS` only counts when all criteria are met at the same time.

Comment: I tried this code and it doesn't work, it sums up the 2 numbers. What I need is the number of times that 2 numbers come up in the series. Example would be that I chose #03 and #22 and out of 343 rows those 2 numbers in each row might show up say 48 times....thanks for your help

Comment: This code does not sum the numbers in cells 'L1' and 'M1'. It sums the counts of how many times the values in 'L1' and 'M1' appear in the range 'C4:C343'. Double check that you entered the formula in exactly as I posted here, because I can copy it into a workbook and it works for me.